# Playscape Unity PublishingKit Demo for iOS Xcode linker Errors

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, playscape

I'm having some trouble trying to build PlaskapePublishingKit 1.6 and Demo for iOS.

At first I was trying to build Publishing SDK 1.6 within an actual Unity game-project. And I was getting some Xcode linker errors at the very end.
It said

```
"_stopLocationTracking", referenced from:
      RegisterMonoModules() in RegisterMonoModules.o
  "_playscape_report_getCustomVariable", referenced from:
      RegisterMonoModules() in RegisterMonoModules.o
  "_setListenerName", referenced from:
      RegisterMonoModules() in RegisterMonoModules.o
  "_playscape_report_clearCustomVariables", referenced from:
      RegisterMonoModules() in RegisterMonoModules.o
  "_playscape_report_StartNewFlow", referenced from:
      RegisterMonoModules() in RegisterMonoModules.o
  "_playscape_report_ReportSocialSubmitScore", referenced from:
      RegisterMonoModules() in RegisterMonoModules.o
```

I got a lot of these errors.
The only thing that goes wrong during the Unity build is some warnings about FacebookSDK:

```
Missing file: /Users/N01/Downloads/PublishingKit-Demo-Unity-master/Assets/Facebook/Editor/iOS/Facebook/Editor/iOS/FbUnityInterface.mm 
Missing file: /Users/N01/Downloads/PublishingKit-Demo-Unity-master/Assets/Facebook/Editor/iOS/Facebook/Editor/iOS/FbUnityInterface.h
Missing file: /Users/N01/Downloads/PublishingKit-Demo-Unity-master/Assets/Facebook/Editor/iOS/Facebook/Scripts/NativeDialogModes.cs
...
Missing file: /Users/beannt/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework > /Users/beannt/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework
```

(that /Users/beannt/Documents/ part looks really fishy, it comes from sample_config.projmods)

So I tried and isolated project and official PublishingKit-Demo. And after generating the Xcode project and building it, adding all of these frameworks:

```
  AddressBook.framework
  AssetsLibrary.framework
  CoreData.framework
  CoreTelephony.framework
  CoreText.framework
  Security.framework
  libc++.dylib
  libz.dylib

  GoogleOpenSource.framework
  GooglePlus.framework
  gpg.framework
```

I still get a bunch of linker errors related to

```
  ***, referenced from:
  RegisterMonoModules() in RegisterMonoModules.o
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you please upgrade to our newest SDK 1.13 through this link: http://dashboard.playscape.com/download/PlayscapePublishingKit-unity.zip . Once you upgrade please let us know if this issue still occurs.

Comment: Can you update which game are you working on so we can contact you? We want to know if this is still an issue.